# Canonical identification of cohomology of nearby fibers in a fiber bundle

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let's say we have a map $f : X \to B$ of complex manifolds, with $B$ simply connected, such that $f$ is diffeomorphic (as a map of smooth manifolds) to the projection $F \times B \to B$. For $b \in B$, we denote its fiber by $X_b:=f^{-1}(b)$. I've seen the following statement:

> The singular cohomology spaces $H^i_{sing}(X_b, \mathbb C)$
>   for $b \in B$ are canonically identiﬁed and the fancy way to say this is to say that $R^if_* \underline{\mathbb C}$ is a
>   local system of $\mathbb C$-vector spaces on $B$.

$\underline{\mathbb C}$ of course denotes the constant sheaf with values in $\mathbb C$. I haven't been able to prove this statement, and I couldn't find a reference to look it up. So I was hoping someone could explain:
 1) How do we get a **canonical** identification of the cohomologies of the fibers?
   2) How is 1) equivalent to $R^if_* \underline{\mathbb C}$ being a
local system of $\mathbb C$-vector spaces on $B$?

Comment: This is called the [Gauß-Manin connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Manin_connection).

Comment: I would like to argue in the other direction: Assume that we have proven that $R^if_* \underline{\mathbb C}$ is a local system. Then, by the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence, there is a flat connection $\nabla$ on the holomorphic vector bundle $R^if_* \underline{\mathbb C} \otimes \mathcal O_B$ such that $R^if_* \underline{\mathbb C}$ arises as its sheaf of flat sections. This $\nabla$ is called the GM connection, and then parallel transport gives us canonical identifications. So let me restate my goal: how to directly prove that $R^if_* \underline{\mathbb C}$ is a locally constant sheaf?

Comment: Look at the section "Intuition" in that wiki page. Given a topological fibration $p\colon E\to B$ and a path $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to B$ which connects $a,b\in B$, there corresponds "parallel transport" $F_a\to F_b$ which is defined up to homotopy, where $F_x:=p^{-1}(x)$ for all $x\in B$. Furthermore, the homotopy type of this "parallel transport" only depends on the homotopy type of the path, and is compatible with the concatenation of paths. Taking cohomology, you get $H^*(F_a)\to H^*(F_b)$. This is the data of connection on cohomology groups.

Answer (score 2):

2) An idea is to consider the cartesian diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    X_{b} @>>> F\times B  \\
    @VVV @VVV  \\
    \{b\} @>>> B
\end{CD}

and then use smooth base change, and the fact that pushforward to the point computes cohomology, to see that the stalk at $b$ of your derived pushforward will be the cohomology of the fiber.

Comment: Ok, using your argument we obtain $(R^if_* \underline{\mathbb C})_b \cong H^i(X_b, \mathbb C)$, thanks! Due to the assumption on $f$, all fibers $X_b$ are (noncanonically) isomorphic, so $R^if_* \underline{\mathbb C}$ has constant stalks. How do we expand on this to show that it is a locally constant sheaf?

Comment: Ok so first of all are you sure your reference has $f$ being exactly $F\times B$? In this case I think it is pretty easy to show that the pushforward is actually a constant sheaf given by the cohomology of $F$. I think what is true and more general is that for $f$ that locally looks like the projection $F\times B\rightarrow B$, you have that the pushfoward is a locally constant sheaf and you show that by taking open subsets where it is actually the projection.